# pleas can you help to detected selfish nodes in manet?

Tags: ns2

I am need coding in ns2  for  Methods To Detect Selfish Nodes 
1.  Reputation-Based System
2.  Credit-Based System
3.  Acknowledgment Based System

Comment: My archive about Selfish-misbehaving-nodes : Selfish-misbehaving-nodes__all.tar.gz → https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SerNjTurevIc82lFPYVYEqS6sB8AlXCT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please can you give paper this work

Comment: Not quite clear what you mean. You already got a link to all the information I have collected (2017 - 2018) about the subject.

Comment: I mean the theoretical side of the project

Comment: Google : https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=ns2+selfish+nodes+in+manet ... → ~41,000 hits.